# How can I format primefaces progressbar's value to always show 2 decimal digits?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I cannot find a way to make the primefaces progress bar to show two decimal digits.

I have googled primefaces progress bar but I couldn't find anything related to format the output value.

Here is the code.

```
<p:progressBar
    value="#{data.financingDataModel.mortgagePercentage}"
    styleClass="animated ui-soba-progress-bar " global="false" style="overflow:hidden">
</p:progressBar>
```

The `mortgagePercentage` type is `Double`.

I want it to show 60.00% instead of just 60%.

Comment: look at the source, it is open...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
  <p:progressBar
     value="#{data.financingDataModel.mortgagePercentage}"
     styleClass="animated ui-soba-progress-bar " global="false" 
     style="overflow:hidden" 
     labelTemplate="#{data.financingDataModel.mortgagePercentage}%">
  </p:progressBar>
```

I only add the `labelTemplate'. It is working on me in PF 7